# Best way of presenting both 720p and 1080p screencasts

Tags: screen-casting

I record screencasts in 720p resolution, but would like to put up 1080p as well. This brings a problem: how can I record videos in 1080p such that they still look OK when scaled down to 720p? I've been thinking about DPI scaling (on Windows), but maybe it's possible to go the other way, i.e. record at 720p and then use some sort of smart scaling to produce a (relatively speaking) high-quality 1080p render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking shooting in 1080p and scaling it down to 720p is not a problem with cameras as I do this all the time and it looks just fine. When I do this I may also be mixing 1080p and 720p raw images, and I always scale to the lowest resolution. When I render a 1080p I will generally render a 720p version as an answer print to view before committing the final cut to a 1080p render. I say this with caution because I have not worked with screencasts or using screen motion capture software.

However, shooting in 720p and trying to make it into 1080p is a losing battle because then you are asking software to make up for pixels that do not exist. You can try it, but I don't think you will like it unless someone makes a software product something like Twixtor that adds frames needed for extra slow motion shots.

Comment: Screencasting has its own set of weird issues for downsampling, though, especially when you're going between resolutions which don't have a reasonably clean ratio between them and when there's a lot of precisely-placed one-pixel-thick horizontal or vertical lines.